# python 3 project - user menu for updating dictionary

Tags: python, function, menu

EDIT REQUESTED:
I created two instances of the menu, one in a function and one outside the function because the initial test prompts the user to enter 5 jersey nums and the player rank, then expects a roster to be printed, then expects the user menu to prompt changes to the roster. 
"Updating dictionary" I meant the roster is created in a dict{} and then the options of the user menu allow for editing the initial dict and then printing a new roster with the changes.

INITIAL POST:
I am having trouble with this code (class assignment, hw not test). The goal is a menu that allows the user to add and delete players from a roster, update their player rating, pull a list of the top x ratings, or simply print a roster. The assignment requires that the initial user input is 5 jersey numbers and their ratings, print a roster, then offer the user menu. I have solved the first 4 tasks. PROBLEM: when accessing menu items to add, delete, update, and rank the first roster that follows the initial 5 entries is being read as the answer instead of the roster that prints to the screen after changes are made. I can't figure out how to set it up so the roster after the initial setup is optional. 
I'm hoping you will see an obvious error in the code that I'm missing. (The indentation looks a little funky to format for pasting in here. I have no indentation errors per the system.)

```
def print_menu():
  print ('\nMENU')
  print ('a - Add player')
  print ('d - Remove player')
  print ('u - Update player rating')
  print ('r - Output players above a rating')
  print ('o - Output roster')
  print ('q - Quit')
  action_in = input('\nChoose an option:\n')

def output_roster():
  listOFjerseys = list(player_stats.keys())
  listOFratings = list(player_stats.values())
  print ('ROSTER')
  a_jersey = sorted (listOFjerseys)
  for x in a_jersey:
     print ("Jersey number: %d, Rating: %d" % (x,player_stats[x]))

player_stats = {}
entry_count = int(5)

for i in range(1,entry_count+1):
   jersey_num = int(input("Enter player %d's jersey number:\n" % i))
   p_rating = int(input("Enter player %d's rating:\n\n" % i))
   player_stats [jersey_num] = (p_rating)

listOFjerseys = list(player_stats.keys())
listOFratings = list(player_stats.values())

print ('ROSTER')
a_jersey = sorted (listOFjerseys)
for x in a_jersey:
   print ("Jersey number: %d, Rating: %d" % (x,player_stats[x]))


    choice = "" #I think this line is unused/unnecessary

    print ('\nMENU')
    print ('a - Add player')
    print ('d - Remove player')
    print ('u - Update player rating')
    print ('r - Output players above a rating')
    print ('o - Output roster')
    print ('q - Quit')
    action_in = input('\nChoose an option:\n')
    while action_in is True and action_in != 'q':
        if action_in == 'a':
            #Add player
            jersey_num = int(input("\nEnter a new player's jerseynumber:\n"))
            p_rating = int(input("Enter the player's rating:\n"))
            player_stats [jersey_num] = (p_rating)
            output_roster()
            print_menu()
        elif action_in == 'd':
            #Delete player
            player = int(input("\nEnter a jersey number:\n"))
            del player_stats[player]
            output_roster()
            print_menu()
        elif action_in == 'u':
            #Update rating
            jersey_num = int(input("\nEnter a jersey number:\n"))
            n_rating = int(input("Enter a new rating for player:\n"))
            player_stats [jersey_num] = (n_rating)
            output_roster()
            print_menu()
        elif action_in == 'r':
            #output > rating
            rankVal = int(input("\nEnter a rating:\n"))
            print ('ABOVE %d\n' % rankVal)
            for m, n in player_stats.values():
                if n > rankVal:
                    print ('Jersey number: %d, Rating: %d\n' % (m,n))
                    print_menu()
        elif action_in == 'o':
            #Output roster
            output_roster()
            print_menu()
    if action_in == 'q':
        #quit
        raise SystemExit()
```

[image]

Comment: Your first **two** functions have indention errors. [Edit] your Question and explain **why** do you have `MENU` **two** times and **what** do you mean with *"updating dictionary"*?

Comment: Sorry, the indention errors aren't in the code. It's something with the format required for getting the code to show here.
The print_menu is there as code for the initial process and then again as 
 a function to call after each menu option is completed, to allow the user to make another choice.

Comment: As it stands, it's not clear which code belongs to `def output_roster()`. You do call `output_roster()`, if inside of `def output_roster()` it's recursive which proably is not what you want. `while action_in is True...` is always `False`, explain **why** you use this.

Comment: I played with the format above so you can see the indents more clearly and tried to resolve the spacing so you can identify the statements contained in the output roster () function. I do not understand the statement by stovfl that "while action_in is True is always False" the intent for the while loop is to move through the user's choices in the menu that are not 'q' to execute the proper statements or call the proper function. Outside the loop is what to do if action_in is 'q' and I had a print output prompting the user to choose again if False. I dropped those 2 lines while troubleshooting.

Comment: You still have **idention errors**! Put this `print(bool(action_in is True))` right after `action_in = input(...` and see if you **ever get `True`**. Read [6.10.3. Identity comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-77). **Reconsider your approach**: *"the intent for the while loop is to move through the user's choices in the menu"*. If the `while` condition ever gets `True` you will end up with a **infinit loop**.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I removed the while statement completely. As stated previously the indents are off due to the formatting for this post. I did attach a snapshot of the code so you could see it as it is in text editor. I ran all of the code through the online homework test system and rewrote it for each error. I was able to complete with full credit. Removing the while statement did help with the process. Also learned how to build a clear function, then ended up not needing it.